# trouble saving java program as one file?

Tags: java

I am required to save and submit my program as only one file. My program has multiple classes and from what I understand so far is that only the main class can be public? What changes would I have to make?

These are the instructions give by our professor:

When you submit your project you should submit only one named xxxx.java 
The main class in this file must be a public class but no other
classes that you use can be public (because only one public class is allowed
in a file).

Comment: I've added the professors instructions. Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: The instructions tell you *exactly* what you have to do -- what confuses you?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-we-keep-more-than-one-class-in-a-single-java-file/answer/Palash-Kanti-Kundu

Comment: I didn't realize it was so literal. I always over think everything in comp sci, but I got it now, thank you.

Comment: Lola, it takes time. Stick with it it's a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the other classes in the same file. However on Java you can only have one public class per file. The other classes can not be public.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I copy the other classes into the main class file and for example remove the "public" from "public class A" ?

Comment: The main class (the class with the main method) will be public. Below that class will be the other classes but they will not use public. (Don't give them an access modifier) Example 

public class MainClass
{
  // code
}

class NextClass
{
 // code
}

Answer (score 1):

You can submit several public classes in a single file, but it won't compile.
Java requires you to have a single public class per .java file, which matches file name exactly. The rest of the classes in the file can be with other access modifiers.